# SQLSTATE[28000] [1045] Access denied for user 'balmain'@'localhost' (using password: YES)

Tags: magento-1.9, database, sql, magento-connect

I'm attempting to connect on my site in magento 1.9 on my work environment. It's shown a page like this:
[image]

Until other yesterday everythig worked perfectly.. Can you help me,please?
Thanks!

Comment: Might be you are using wrong username/psw/db name

Comment: Please check your db username and password data is proper or not in file magento root/app/etc/local.xml?

Comment: yes, I do.. The problem is resolved!

Comment: The password in my root/app/etc/local.xml is something like: 34PV-(RF1h] Is that encoded? How can I put my password in there?

Answer (score 1):

Check the below steps

1. **DB Checks** : Make sure the Db still exists , Ensure that user balmain'@'localhost has been granted access to the database in question.
2. **Xammp/WAMP/ Server Checks** : Check for MYSql service is
   running , check if the port is changed or not .
3. **Magento Checks** : clear cache ,Disable all 3rd party modules on the server , Make sure you have reset the file permissions [Magento Wiki](http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/groups/227/resetting_file_permissions)

If you are still getting error messages, verify that the username, password and database name `/app/etc/local.xml`

Comment: Thank you.. This site isn't in my local machine.. I cleared cache but the problem remains.. How can I do the step 1? Thank you!

Comment: how do you have access to that DB ? by ssh or phpmyadmin(added more probable solutions)

Comment: The password in my root/app/etc/local.xml is something like: 34PV-(RF1h] Is that encoded? How can I put my password in there?

Answer (score 0):

I resolved my problem by setting db accesses into app/etc/local.xml